# Alarm system in Android

Tags: android, onesignal

I need to create an alarm system in android that controls when a value reaches a predetermined limit send me a notification.
I have no idea where to start, I saw tutorials for onesignal, firebase and android, I could implement an example with onesignal and from the onesignal page I can send a notification and receive it from my application, but what I don't know how to follow is how to connect with my database and get the value that indicates that I have to send an alert.

Can someone tell me what to look for? How to guide me?
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send push notification to an Android client, for example when the product price is lowered to 50 USD. So you need to check the changed price and when the price is changed and the new price is suitable for informing your Android client, you can use OneSignal Create Notification API. Of course you can use another tool like Firebase etc. You can send push notification via OneSignal API, Create Notification method from any platform. You can check it and if this scenario is good enough for your requirement then you can try it.